# Execute python script after Tortoise update finishes

Tags: tortoisesvn

How can I execute something - in this case a python script - after tortoise finishes updating a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a [client-side post-update](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) hook script.